# Folder Statistics in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to summarize how much data has been written to a folder in my Data Lake. What is the best way to do this? Should I use a U-SQL job? HDInsights?

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do this:

1. If it is a one-time operation, you can use Azure Storage Explorer (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/), navigate to the Data Lake Store folder and get the size for it.
2. If you want a programmatic way to do this, Data Lake Store provides a WebHDFS compliant API that can list several folder attributes: GETCONTENTSUMMARY. You can see more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis.

Hope this helps

José

Comment: Hi Jose, Would you know how to do this with ADLS gen2

Comment: For option-2, note it works only with Gen1. And not Gen2 as per this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316970/does-azure-data-lake-gen2-provides-webhdfs-rest-apis

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python code to loop through the files.
Refer here: https://cloudarchitected.com/2019/05/computing-total-storage-size-of-a-folder-in-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2/

In case you would like to quickly cross check this:

> Download the Azure Storage Explorer from Windows Application
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/storage-explorer/
>
> Open the folder which you would like to view the size details.
>
> On the top bar menu choose  More -> **Folder Statistics** will help
>   you get the details of the Directory including the size in bytes. 
>   Refer the attachment [sample snapshot of the Azure Storage Explorer
>   Menu[1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1DuZ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script which will help to get folder/files statistics.And also please verify all variables with vaules as per your environment.

```
import csv, os, datetime,configparser
from azure.datalake.store import core,lib

# Returns the size of each subdirectory 
def getUsage(adls_client,data,level):
    
    temp=[]
    # Split the path by '/' and store in list
    for i in data:
        temp.append(i.split('/'))

    # Prepare PathList by removing the filenames 
    path=[]
    pathList=[]
    for i in temp:

        # Ensure Depth of the Path is not crossing level
        path=[]
        if len(i)-1 >= level:
            maxDepth = level
        else:
            maxDepth = len(i)-1
            
        for j in range(maxDepth):
        
            if i[j] not in path or i[j] != '_SUCCESS':
                path.append(i[j])
        
        pathList.append(path)
    
    # Remove duplicates
    uniquePaths = set(tuple(x) for x in pathList)
    pathsPreparedDU= list("/".join(x) for x in uniquePaths)
    
    # Get usage for the directories from prepared paths
    answers=[]
    temp=[]
    temp2=""
    blankLevelCnt =0 

    for i in pathsPreparedDU:
        temp=[]
        temp2=""
        usage=adls_client.du(i, deep=True, total=True)
        temp.append(i.split('/'))
        for item in temp:
            if len(item) < level+1:
                blankLevelCnt = (level+1) - len(item)
        temp2=temp2+i
        for j in range(blankLevelCnt):
            temp2=temp2+"/"
        temp2=temp2+str(usage)
        answers.append([temp2])

    # add element for CSV header
    csvList = []
    temp=[]
    temp.append("Date/Time")    
    for i in range(level):
        temp.append("Level "+str(i+1))

    temp.append("Size (Bytes)")    
    temp.append("Size (KB)")    
    temp.append("Size (MB)")    
    temp.append("Size (GB)")    
    temp.append("Size (TB)")    

    csvList.append(temp)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in answers:
        usageBytes = int(i[0].split('/')[-1])
        usageKBytes = round(usageBytes/1024,2)
        usageMBytes = round(usageKBytes/1024,2)
        usageGBytes = round(usageMBytes/1024,2)
        usageTBytes = round(usageGBytes/1024,2)
        csvList.append((str(now)[:16]+"/"+i[0]+"/"+str(usageKBytes)+"/"+str(usageMBytes)+"/"+str(usageGBytes)+"/"+str(usageTBytes)).split('/'))

    return csvList

# Returns the alds_client object
def connectADLS(tenant_id,app_id,app_key, adls_name):
    adls_credentials = lib.auth(tenant_id=tenant_id,client_secret=app_key,client_id=app_id)
    return core.AzureDLFileSystem(adls_credentials, store_name=adls_name)

# Returns the all subdirectories under the root directory
def getSubdirectories(adls_client,root_dir):
    return adls_client.walk(root_dir)

# Write to CSV
def writeCSV(root_dir,csvList):
    
    fileprefixes = root_dir.split('/')
    prefix = "root-"
    while('' in fileprefixes) : 
        fileprefixes.remove('') 

    if len(fileprefixes) > 0:
        prefix = ""
        for i in fileprefixes:
            prefix = prefix + i + "-" 
    
    x = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    filename = prefix+""+ x +".csv"

    with open(filename, "w+") as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile,lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(csvList)

    csvFile.close()
    print("file Generated")
    print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=filename;]%s' % (filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # 1. Parse config file and get service principal details
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read('config.ini')
    
    tenant_id=config['SERVICE_PRINCIPAL']['tenant_id']
    app_id=config['SERVICE_PRINCIPAL']['app_id']
    app_key=config['SERVICE_PRINCIPAL']['app_key']
    adls_name = config['ADLS_ACCT']['adls_name'] 
    root_dir = config['ADLS_ACCT']['root_dir'] 
    level = config['ADLS_ACCT']['level'] 

    # 2. Connect to ADLS 
    adls_client = connectADLS(tenant_id,app_id,app_key, adls_name)

    # 3. recursively lists all files
    data = getSubdirectories(adls_client,root_dir)

    # 4. Get usage for the directories
    csvList = getUsage(adls_client,data,int(level))

    # 5. Upload report to blob
    writeCSV(root_dir,csvList)
```