# Does Azure Data Lake Gen2 provides WebHDFS REST API's?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-hdinsight

If no, is it possible to use WebHDFS API from HDInsight to connect with ADL Gen2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, ADLS Gen2 does not provides WebHDFS REST APIs.

Azure Data Lake Gen1 has WebHDFS-compatible Rest APIs, where Azure Data Lake Gen2 has Azure Blob Service Rest API.

[image]

Reference: [ADLS Gen1 Compatibility with Hadoop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-compare-storage-options#overview-of-azure-data-lake-storage-gen1) and [ADLS Gen1 vs ADLS Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-upgrade).

Hope this helps.